# Using git to VC a live website containing files in multiple locations

Tags: git, version-control, web

I have seen multiple people use git to VC their websites directly, and for a few instances I've been thinking about doing the same. However, I can't figure out how to do the following:

Let's say I have two websites on a machine, with html and etc. located at:

- /var/www/html/prj_a
- /var/www/html/prj_b

And I have cgi scripts at:

- /var/www/cgi-bin/prj_a/
- /var/www/cgi-bin/prj_b/

So I practically have two "parallel" git projects under /var/www/
I'd think someone has this figured out, but I was unable to find that much out with google...

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Ways I've thought about:

- Use save cgi and html in different repositories
- Save the sites like this:

  - sites/a/html
  - sites/a/cgi-bin/
  - ...

  and then symlink those folders to under /var/www/{html,cgi-bin}/project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done on a few occasions in cases where for whatever reason keeping the project together in a single location and symlinking the different locations to that is I create a separate project dir for git and `mount --bind` the locations under that (like symlinks but invisible to git).

In my above example creating symlinking `/var/www/cgi-bin/prj_a/` to `projects/prj_a/cgi-bin/` would propably make more sense unless symlinks were forbidden by the server configuration but I'll stick to that example.

Example project structure:

```
HTML code and assets
/var/www/html/prj_a  
/var/www/html/prj_b

CGI-scripts
/var/www/cgi-bin/prj_a/  
/var/www/cgi-bin/prj_b/
```

I create a dir somewhere else:

```
projects/prj_a/
```

Mount the other directories under that

```
mkdir projects/prj_a/{html,cgi-bin}
mount --bind /var/www/cgi-bin/prj_a/ projects/prj_a/cgi-bin
mount --bind /var/www/html/prj_a/ projects/prj_a/html
```

Now I have a directory structure:

```
projects/
    prj_a/
        cgi-bin/ (points to /var/www/cgi-bin/prj_a/)
        html/    (points to /var/www/html/prj_a/)
```

Now I can use `projects/prj_a/` as a git repository. Git does not see that the files are located elsewhere.